# React Redux: How to properly return iteratable array in reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action, reducers

I'm working in React Redux, and I am trying to return a value from a simple array in my reducer. Here are my short files:

**App.js**

```
let arr = [{"name": "Matthew"}];

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(action1(arr));

    return(
        <div>
            <List />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**List.js**

```
function List(){
    const val = useSelector(getVals);

    return(
        <div>
            {val}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Actions.js**

```
export function action1(arr){
    return { type: ADD_STORE, arr};
}
```

**Reducer.js**

```
function AddToStore(state = [], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_STORE:
            return [...action.name, ...state];
    }
}

export default AddToStore;
```

This is giving me the error "object is not iterable." Why? Instead of an array, if I just pass a string, for example "Matthew", I can print it out fine by returning [...action, ...state].

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because in your store you're trying to return an array instead of an object. More about redux principals here: https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#single-source-of-truth

App.js

```
let objNames = {names: [{"name": "Matthew"}]};

function App() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    dispatch(action1(arr));

    return(
        <div>
            <List />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Reducer.js

```
function AddToStore(state, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_STORE:
            return {...action.names, ...state};
    }
}

export default AddToStore;
```

And changed the action.js to pass in objNames instead of arr.

Comment: As shown in the initial state of the reducer, `state = []`, it is an array so the return is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by change curly braces by [].

```js
const initialState = {
  clients: [],
  loading: false,
};
export default function clientReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch (action.type) {

    case ADD_CLIENT:
          return [action.clients, state];
 default:
      return state;
}
}
```

Comment: Please have a look on following article;
https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/